# Using a second branch in git-svn

Tags: git, svn, branch

I need to know how to (properly) handle multiple svn branches with git-svn, on a Windows local machine (git version 2.6.4.windows.1).

My local repo was set up with:

```
prompt> git svn init svn://svn.internal.albert.com/Trunk/stable
prompt> git svn fetch
```

and has been humming away happily for *years*.

Now there is a new branch creates at `svn://svn.internal.albert.com/Branches/Baker`
and I know exactly which commit number (`@12345`) it was copied from if that's helpful.

I want that to appear in my local repo, as a normal git branch, so I can manipulate it (add new commits on the end by cherry-picking, rebase the whole thing, etc.) and then dcommit it back up to the proper place in svn.

My config file shows the section as:

```
// existing situation
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = svn://svn.internal.albert.com/Trunk/stable
    fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
```

and doesn't mention "branches" or other entries under svn-remote.

I *tried* re-arranging it as

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = svn://svn.internal.albert.com
    fetch = Trunk/stable:refs/remotes/git-svn
    fetch = Branches/Baker:refs/remotes/svn2015
    branches = Branches/*:refs/remotes/svn-branches/*
```

and ran `git svn fetch --follow-parent` but it's fetching the world and has been running for a long time, with branches other than the one I want it seems from the names.

How should I do this to just sync the second branch that I'm interested in, and not get it confused with the first?

Comment: Well I certainly wouldn't try rebasing because SVN has no such concept; I'd be interested in knowing how git-svn handles branches in general however.

Comment: The docs mention rebase and that dcommit uses rebase internally.

Comment: Anyway, let me "see" it and do what I can with it. I'll worry about the  specific limitations later.